# Passing COM Interface by reference via COM Interop

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have the following COM Object implemented in C#

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("AAAABBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEE-FFFFAAAABBBB")]
class Foo : IFoo, IBar
{
   // Implementation
}
```

I have the following COM interface into another COM object implemented in C++.

```
[Guid("FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAAFFFFEEEE")]
[TypeLibType(4160)]
public interface IAcceptFoo2 : IAcceptFoo
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void AcceptFoo(ref IFoo foo, IOther other, bool Check);
     // Additional methods
}
```

I am calling this interface from C# as such:

```
Foo fooConcrete = new Foo();
IFoo fooInterface = fooConcrete as IFoo;
acceptFooConcrete.AcceptFoo(ref fooInterface, other, check);
```

I can debug the native code and I see that the `foo` parameter is a valid pointer (but has a `nullptr` for `_vfptr`), however the object performs the following `QueryInterface`

```
IBarPtr spBar;
HRESULT hr = foo->QueryInterface(IID_IBar, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&spBar));
```

This `QueryInterface` call to get the `IBar` interface also implemented on `Foo` generates an `Access Exception`.

> Exception thrown: read access violation.

I'm curious if I'm missing some sort of Marshaling because the `IFoo` parameter is passed as `ref`.

Comment: Where/how is defined foo? Also, since interfaces references are just (immutable) pointers, they are passed as `in` or `out`, not as ref.

Comment: @SimonMourier `Foo` is defined in a `TLB` file that was added as a reference to the `C#` project. `IAcceptFoo2` is also defined in that same `TLB` file. When the `TLB` was added as a reference to the `C#` project it generated the interface definition with `ref` and won't compile if the provided parameter isn't provided as ref.

Comment: Do you have the original definition of these interfaces?